# refresh javascript using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, reload

when i use ajax to reload a div on a page, it works, but not when I try to reload a script. my javascript is dynamic, from a database, and so is my div. here is my code:

```
        <ul id="classes">
            <?php
            $email = 'thomas990428@me.com_classes';

            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `$email` ORDER BY period"); if (!$result) echo mysqli_error(); else // ok, do your thing.

            $classcount = 1;

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {

              $period = $row['period'];
              $teacher = $row['teacher'];
              $subject = $row['subject'];
              $subjecto = strtolower($subject);
              $subjecto = str_replace(' ', '', $subjecto);
              $grade = $row['grade'];

              echo "<li id='button" . $classcount . "' class='button' onclick='" . $subjecto . "(),homework" . $classcount . "()'><div class='deletebutton' onclick='deleteclass" . $subjecto . "()'>X</div><span class='course'>" . $classcount . ". " . $subject . "</span></li>\n";

              $classcount += 1;

              }

            ?>
    <script>

        <?php
        $email = 'thomas990428@me.com_classes';

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `$email`");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {

          $period = $row['period'];
          $teacher = $row['teacher'];
          $subject = $row['subject'];
          $subjecto = strtolower($subject);
          $subjecto = str_replace(' ', '', $subjecto);
          $grade = $row['grade'];

          echo "function deleteclass" . $subjecto . "() { \n";
          echo "var hi = confirm('Are you absolutely sure you want to permantly delete this class? This cannot be undone.'); \n";
          echo "if (hi==true) \n";
          echo "{ \n";
          echo "document.getElementById('hiddenframe').src='deleteclass.php?class=".$subjecto."';";
          echo "closeedit();";
          echo "refreshclasses();";
          echo "} \n";
          echo "else \n";
          echo "{} \n";
          echo "} \n";

          }

        ?>


    </script>
        </ul>
        <iframe id="hiddenframe"></iframe>
```

so basically it refreshes the ul but not the script. I need it to refresh both in order to do what i need it to do. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a new `<script>` tag to the page? See [example](http://javascript.about.com/library/bladdjs.htm).

Comment: You can either do as Aiias said, or you can have a static JS function with dynamic variables returned from AJAX. But unfortunately you can't have a dynamic "javascript + php script" on client side alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read comments first, and...

On examining your code, why don't you do this instead?

```
function deleteClass(subjecto, period, teacher, ...)
```

and

```
onclick='deleteClass(" . $subjecto . ", " . $period. ", " . $teacher. ")'
```

If you just want it to work for now, you can do this:

replace:

```
<div class='deletebutton' onclick='deleteclass" . $subjecto . "()'>X</div>
```

to:

```
<div class='deletebutton' onclick='deleteclass(" . $subjecto . ")'>X</div>
```

and replace the whole echo <script> part with:

```
function deleteclass(subjecto){
    var hi = confirm('Are you absolutely sure you want to permantly delete this class? This cannot be undone.');
    if (hi==true)
    {
        document.getElementById('hiddenframe').src='deleteclass.php?class='+subjecto;
        closeedit();
        refreshclasses();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using period or teacher in the function, but I added them just to give you an idea.

Comment: sorry, im kinda new to javascript, so how do i pull the 'subjecto' out of the argument and use it in `document.getElementById('hiddenframe').src='deleteclass.php?class=`?